# Adding allowVolumeExpansion: true to default storage classes in AKS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-aks

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv#built-in-storage-classes) says the following:

> These default storage classes don't allow you to update the volume size once created. To enable this ability, add the `allowVolumeExpansion: true` line to one of the default storage classes, or create you own custom storage class. You can edit an existing storage class using the `kubectl edit sc` command. For more information on storage classes and creating your own, see Storage options for applications in AKS.

I've tried editing the the `default` YAML (which just looks like JSON and not YAML) in the Kubernetes dashboard:

```
{
  "kind": "StorageClass",
  "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/default",
    "uid": "<uid>",
    "resourceVersion": "3891497",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-14T01:34:03Z",
    "labels": {
      "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"storage.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"StorageClass\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class\":\"true\"},\"labels\":{\"kubernetes.io/cluster-service\":\"true\"},\"name\":\"default\"},\"parameters\":{\"cachingmode\":\"ReadOnly\",\"kind\":\"Managed\",\"storageaccounttype\":\"Standard_LRS\"},\"provisioner\":\"kubernetes.io/azure-disk\"}\n",
      "storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"
    }
  },
  "provisioner": "kubernetes.io/azure-disk",
  "parameters": {
    "cachingmode": "ReadOnly",
    "kind": "Managed",
    "storageaccounttype": "Standard_LRS"
  },
  "reclaimPolicy": "Delete",
  "volumeBindingMode": "Immediate",
  "allowVolumeExpansion": "true"
}
```

Which results in:

```
StorageClass in version "v1" cannot be handled as a StorageClass: v1.StorageClass.AllowVolumeExpansion: ReadBool: expect t or f, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|ansion": "true" }|..., bigger context ...|ingMode": "Immediate", "allowVolumeExpansion": "true" }|...
```

Also:

```
{
  "kind": "StorageClass",
  "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/default",
    "uid": "<uid>",
    "resourceVersion": "3891497",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-14T01:34:03Z",
    "labels": {
      "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"storage.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"StorageClass\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class\":\"true\"},\"labels\":{\"kubernetes.io/cluster-service\":\"true\"},\"name\":\"default\"},\"parameters\":{\"cachingmode\":\"ReadOnly\",\"kind\":\"Managed\",\"storageaccounttype\":\"Standard_LRS\"},\"provisioner\":\"kubernetes.io/azure-disk\"}\n",
      "storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"
    }
  },
  "provisioner": "kubernetes.io/azure-disk",
  "parameters": {
    "cachingmode": "ReadOnly",
    "kind": "Managed",
    "storageaccounttype": "Standard_LRS",
    "allowVolumeExpansion": "true"
  },
  "reclaimPolicy": "Delete",
  "volumeBindingMode": "Immediate"
}
```

Which results in:

```
StorageClass.storage.k8s.io "default" is invalid: parameters: Forbidden: updates to parameters are forbidden.
```

Also tried all of the following with `kubectl edit sc`:

```
$ kubectl edit sc default allowVolumeExpansion: true          
Error from server (NotFound): storageclasses.storage.k8s.io "allowVolumeExpansion:" not found
Error from server (NotFound): storageclasses.storage.k8s.io "true" not found

$ kubectl edit sc default "allowVolumeExpansion: true"
Error from server (NotFound): storageclasses.storage.k8s.io "allowVolumeExpansion: true" not found

$ kubectl edit sc/default allowVolumeExpansion: true
error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/<resource_name>'

$ kubectl edit sc/default "allowVolumeExpansion: true"
error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/<resource_name>'
```

What is the correct way of accomplishing this? Would be helpful if an example was in the documentation.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Comment: Any updates for this issue? I didn't see anything, solved the problem or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not meet the issue you got. The `allowVolumeExpansion` is a property of the storage class, not the parameter and it requires the boolean value. You can see it in [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#storageclass-v1-storage-k8s-io).

I think you mistake setting its value. In my test, I add the property in the YAML file like this:

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

**Not**

```
allowVolumeExpansion: "true"
```

So I think you need to change the line into this:

```
"allowVolumeExpansion": true
```

Comment: Very strange. Pretty sure I tried that before through the Dashboard and ran into errors. This time it worked.